# Why is 'Create New Content' disabled

Tags: experience-editor

I am trying to add a new component into a sitecore page using the Experience Editor. I want my component to read from a datasource item. I want to be able to create content items (as datasource) from the experience editor, however the 'Create New Content' is disabled, why is that?
Sitecore 8.1 Update 3

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is normal behaviour if you didn't set Datasource Template for your rendering. If you don't set the template is it normal to not enable that button because you don't know what kind of template your component support like a datasource.

Please check this link to find more information : https://varunvns.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/page-editor-experience-set-the-datasource-template-for-the-presentation-component/